# L’usage de « vouloir » dans la tournure « l’histoire veut que »

Tags: usage

J’ai constaté plusieurs fois la tournure un peu bizarre de « l’histoire veut que ». D’après plusieurs [traductions](https://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/l%27histoire+veut+que.html), on dirait qu’elle est synonyme de « dire que ». Est-ce que je me trompe? Serait-il juste de l’utiliser avec d’autres noms (les gens, les choses)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On peut effectivement remplacer *vouloir* par *dire* dans le cas cité dans la question mais les deux verbes ne sont pas entièrement synonymes. *Dire* est le verbe « neutre », il n'exprime rien d'autre que l'expression de la parole. Dans *vouloir* il y a à la fois l'expression de la parole, plus un jugement de celui qui rapporte cette parole exprimée par quelqu'un d'autre.

[Définition du *Robert*](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/vouloir) :

> **II**
> ◊ Donner pour vrai, affirmer. La légende veut que (+ subjonctif).

*Dictionnaire culturel en langue Française<sup>1</sup> :*

> vouloir que... affirmer (par un acte de jugement volontaire plus que par référence à la réalité) **→ prétendre**.

Voici une phrase tirée d'un quotidien régional ([Le Dauphiné Libéré](https://www.ledauphine.com/isere-sud/2019/02/24/l-histoire-du-dimanche-a-la-chasse-au-loup), 24 févr. 2019) :

> Officiellement la tranquillité du petit chaperon rouge remonte à 1937. Cette année-là, **l'histoire veut**<sup>2</sup> que les loups aient disparus de France, avec un "dernier spécimen" abattu dans le Limousin.

La journaliste qui a rédigé ça indique par l'emploi du verbe vouloir qu'elle fait plus que rapporter ce qui est dit : elle met en cause la véracité de ce qui est dit (ce que, d'ailleurs, elle développe dans son billet).

On peut employer *vouloir* avec ce sens avec d'autre sujets que *histoire*.

> **Ceux qui veulent que**<sup>2</sup> les hommes soient tous bons ou tous méchants, absolument grands ou petits, ne connaissent pas la nature. (Citation de *[Vauvenargues](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JicyC9774pUC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=%22ceux%20qui%20veulent%20que%20les%20hommes%20soient%20tous%20bons%22&source=bl&ots=lXGRF_QVhw&sig=ACfU3U0YSCbnvh2ndrC59otfLHMJ7TNmBQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM59yZpNTzAhVJ1xoKHTFqCEEQ6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=%22ceux%20qui%20veulent%20que%20les%20hommes%20soient%20tous%20bons%22&f=false)*, 1828)

> **l'opinion veut que**<sup>2</sup> les coupables soient punis. Sans doute, mais pas seulement. (Un compte rendu de [séance du Sénat](http://www.senat.fr/cra/s20090306/b_s20090306_82.html),2009).

Par contre il semble difficile de l'employer quand le sujet est un objet, il faut que le sujet ait la capacité de distribuer une parole.

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>sld Alain Rey, Éditions Le Robert, 2005.</sup>
<sup>2.</sup> <sup>C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>

Comment: Le dernier exemple ne *voudrait-il* pas une relecture bienveillante ? On doit pouvoir rajouter la pensée, celle de la journaliste,  à la dernière parole :-) .

Comment: @Personne Je sens que je rate quelque chose... j'ai vu une typo en relisant, mais je suis sûre que ce n'est pas ce que tu voulais dire. Je ne vois absolument pas, un autre indice ?

Comment: En fait, c'est la pensée qui est vivante et la source de sa manifestation, cf. la parole du dernier paragraphe, cela englobe aussi l'écriture (qui est un objet tactile) de la journaliste … mille-z-excuses pour cet essai de contraction de texte loupè !

Comment: D'accord.... c'est pour ça que je ne pouvais pas comprendre, pour moi  la parole c'est l'expression écrite aussi bien qu'orale de la pensée.